# PHP query to meet a condition has to be present in a second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

First has the following:

```
id | Company       | Field  | Country
-------------------------------------
1  | Widgets Inc   | Parts  | USA   
2  | Moo Corp      | Toys   | GBR   
3  | Dingles S.A   | Music  | GER   
4  | Deutsh Import | Import | AUT   
5  | Clean Inc     | Clean  | USA
```

and second table

```
id | Employee     | Company_id | Country
----------------------------------------
1  | Paul Allen   | 2          | USA   
2  | Andrew Cur   | 2          | GBR   
3  | Paul Hanz    | 4          | GER   
4  | Angela Dow   | 1          | AUT   
5  | Dana Loconto | 4          | USA
```

I want to filter (mysql query on php) the first table with ONLY the companies that actually have an employee on the second table. The ones with no employees should be ignored.

Thank you for your advice

EDIT: Using INNER JOIN seems to fix this, but then I have a different problem.
If I use INNER JOIN as suggested below, it gives me one result for EACH time the occurence happens on the join table.

For example: Using my table below, it will return the company id 2 twice, and id 4 twice. To better explain, I'm using this to generate a list of the companies that actually have employees, but I don't need it to repeat itself everytime it finds a new employee of the same company. Not sure if I'm making myself clear.

```
SELECT C.id, C.field, C.country
FROM first_table as C
INNER JOIN second_table as E ON E.company_id = C.id
```

This returns the following

```
Moo Corp       | Toys   | USA
Moo Corp       | Toys   | USA
Deutsch Import | Import | AUT
Widgets Inc    | Parts  | USA
Deutsch Import | Import | AUT
```

And what I was expecting is only

```
Moo Corp
Deutsch Import
Widget Inc
```

Any extra help?

Comment: Have you try an inner join?

Comment: Not really a PHP question as this would be best achieved in pure SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an inner join :

```
SELECT C.id, C.field, C.country
FROM first_table as C
INNER JOIN second_table as E ON E.company_id = C.id AND E.employee is not null
```

Or as suggested in the comment, if the `second_table` data about employee only exist if there is a company :

```
SELECT C.id, C.field, C.country
FROM first_table as C
INNER JOIN second_table as E ON E.company_id = C.id
```

It works like this :

- You select the element you want (here only element from table_one)
- You make your `inner join` based on the common field (here `company_id` from second_table and `id` from first_table)
- You add your condition on the `inner_join`, here `E.employee is not null`, adapt according to how it looks when no employee (maybe empty string, maybe 0, I don't know)
- The inner join will make you return only element that respect this condition

EDIT :

To only get one result by company, add this at the end :

```
GROUP BY C.company
```

But you need to add C.company to your SELECT before

Comment: If no employee = no line in second table, you can do without `AND E.employee is not null` since it's an inner join.

Comment: You're right, I don't know how his database works so I add the condition but I edited my anwser, thanks

Comment: Yes, if no emplyee = no line on table, that is the idea. I will put that to test, thank you!

Comment: I updated my question with a new problem this solutions has brought. Thank you.

Comment: I edit my anwser too, just add `GROUP BY C.company` (if you want only one company) and add C.company to your SELECT list

Comment: Glad to help you :)